# Why images are combined (ffmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create video from images (one image per frame).

`ffmpeg -framerate 21.533 -i %d.bmp -i z.wav -r 21.533 -t 120 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -b:a 128k z.mp4`

When I watch resulting video I see (at least at the end of video) that frames are combined with each other (2 images on each frame overlaps with different transparency ratio). I seems like when source and destination frame rate mismatch.

I can remove `-framerate` and `-r` options but result will be the same (with 25 fps).

What's the problem?
How to fix it?

Comment: Share your input sequence.

Comment: @Gyan, http://xk8.ru/f/temp/z.zip (resulting video is included, see it at ≈ 45 sec)... actually I need to use ZMBV codec but result is the same.

Comment: But there's no problem when I add scale option: `ffmpeg -framerate 21.533 -i %d.bmp -i z.wav -r 21.533 -t 120 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -vf scale=-2:1080 -sws_flags neighbor z.mp4` (http://xk8.ru/f/temp/z1080.mp4). Besides scaling to 700+ lines (720, 800, 1080, 1200) is ok (no overlapping) but 600 or less is not. Why?

Comment: I don't see any frame blending - which frames do you see it in?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that KMPlayer plays with frame mixing/overlapping.
The video is ok... Another player plays ok...